# Reading gzip files inside gzip file using Java

Tags: java, gzip

Using Java I have to read text files which are inside gz file which is in another .tar.gz

gz_ltm_logs.tar.gz is the filename. It then has files ltm.1.gz, ltm.2.gz inside it and then these files have text files in them.

I wanted to do it using java.util.zip.* only but if it is impossible then I can look at other libraries.
I thought I will be able to do it using java.util.zip. But doesn't seem straightforward

Comment: Gzip can not compress several files into one by itself. Are we talking about a tar.gz ?

Comment: yes gz_ltm_logs.tar.gz is the filename. I thought it was just equalant to .gz. It then has files ltm.1.gz, ltm.2.gz inside it

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code to give you an idea. This method will try to extract a given tar.gz file to outputFolder.

```
public static void extract(File input, File outputFolder) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    GZIPInputStream gzipFile = new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(input));
    ByteOutputStream tarStream = new ByteOutputStream();

    int gzipLengthRead;
    while ((gzipLengthRead = gzipFile.read(buffer)) > 0){
        tarStream.write(buffer, 0, gzipLengthRead);
    }

    gzipFile.close();

    org.apache.tools.tar.TarInputStream tarFile = null;

    // files inside the tar
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {
        tarFile = new org.apache.tools.tar.TarInputStream(tarStream.newInputStream());
        tarStream.close();

        TarEntry entry = null;

        while ((entry = tarFile.getNextEntry()) != null) {

            String outFilename = entry.getName();

            if (entry.isDirectory()) {
                File directory = new File(outputFolder, outFilename);
                directory.mkdirs();
            } else {
                File outputFile = new File(outputFolder, outFilename);
                File outputDirectory = outputFile.getParentFile();
                if (!outputDirectory.exists()) {
                    outputDirectory.mkdirs();
                }
                out = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

                // Transfer bytes from the tarFile to the output file
                int innerLen;

                while ((innerLen = tarFile.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buffer, 0, innerLen);
                }
                out.close();
            }
        }
    } finally {
        if (tarFile != null) {
            tarFile.close();
        }
        if (out != null) {
            out.close();
        }
    }
}
```